# Put a button in certain spot of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

i am fairly new to coding and i got this typing script online and then created a button, the button links to a different page that I haven't created yet. The issue i am facing is that i cant get the button to stay in one place while the typing script is running, it moves around, is there a way i can put it in a fixed position maybe by the bottom left of the screen. my code is bellow, Thanks!

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 3;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 5000;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 5%;
  top: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 24px 80px;
  border: 1px solid #a12727;
  border-radius: 98px;
  background: #bd4aff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#bd4aff), to(#992727));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bd4aff, #992727);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bd4aff, #992727);
  -webkit-box-shadow: #ff5959 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #ff5959 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  box-shadow: #ff5959 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 0px;
  font: normal normal bold 37px arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  background: #e359ff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e359ff), to(#b62f2f));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e359ff, #b62f2f);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e359ff, #b62f2f);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active {
  background: #712c99;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#712c99), to(#982727));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #712c99, #982727);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #712c99, #982727);
}

.button:after {
  content: "\0000a0";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0 -4px -6px 4px;
  position: relative;
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAABBUlEQVRIibXVMUrEQBQG4I9FrMXKUjyBhVjZeAULD7F2VoLHELEQKzsvINZWgldwFQutLCwWRFhisQ6Mw2Yzk4mvfC+8L/OTIfytMd6x65/qDA0+sDPEwlFLfx13QyBtQIxUxbUMCMitipN0AQHpHVcOECPFceUCASmOqwQISFFcpUCMZMXVBwhIVlx9gYB0xlUDxEhrXLVAQFrjGgIIyMWiwUqPZd84xVfSfxwKWMUrbnIezonoBW9J7yj3bbqACfZxnvT3sJ2LxBX+aA2esPXb38A0mjW4rAGesZnMrhNgirVS4BD3C5Yzv0yzBDkuBZbVCA/R8hlOhgTgAJ+4Mr+5nV/hD3mmNbSMQ+JfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") no-repeat left center transparent;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ce3635;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      padding-top: 10em;
    }
    
    * {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="js/script.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <h1>


    <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="1000" data-type='[ "Hi, Welcome to DShroff.com", "A Website created entirely from scratch by me.", "Click the button below to go to games or wait here to be redirected to home."]'>
      <span class="wrap"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:50px 0px" href="https://games.dshroff.com">Click to go to Games</a>

    </a>





    </a>
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` of button . Button will get out of flow from document and will appear below the text

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `position:fixed`?
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

And then manipulate `top` and `left`.

Ah, maybe more important, put the button inside div, and style the div.
[image]

Comment: thanks! I tried this, but now the button will not show up, insted it just shows the button text. the code is here https://codepen.io/devins/pen/GRQVgNB

Comment: @DevinShroff there are some unusual things going on in this codepen and I cannot understand whats going one there. Just for your information (I know you are a beginner)- its better to have one <style></style> block. I would take this example from w3 as sort of template for your code: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed